# jidesoft pivotgrid

Tags: java, jide

I want to use jidesoft's pivotgrid for my application.But I wonder if this component supports exporting excel,csv,pdf and printing utilities.I searced jidesoft website, but I didn't find anything.

Could anyone help experienced with this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at the feature list it obviously does not:

1, It would be advertised, because these features are business values that should be well advertised

2, It would be a complete misunderstanding of Swing component concept if such features would go into a Swing component. All it should give you is access to its underlying data model and a different component should deal with any data transformation.

You could make these transformations quite easily with Java libraries:

- CSV: simple text file writing
- Excel: it can read CSV, but if really needed go with Apache POI
- PDF: iText is your best friend